# React-Native Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.['DRAWER'])

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native-base

How do I resolve this error? I've tried but still error ..

[DrawerLayoutAndroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkVWH.png)

and this is my code root.js :

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={250}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
    ref={'DRAWER'}>
      <Navigator
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{component: Home}}
        ref={(nav) => { this.appNav = nav; }}  />
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

and this is my code in Home.js :

```
handleMenuPress() {
this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
```

}

```
<Header searchBar rounded>
     <Item>
         <Icon name="menu" onPress={this.handleMenuPress}/>
         <Input placeholder="Cari Rumah Sakit" />
         <Icon active name="search" />
      </Item>
      <Button transparent>
          <Text>Search</Text>
       </Button>
 </Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `this` is not in scope of handleMenuPress.
Try changing handleMenuPress to an arrow function.

```
handleMenuPress = () => {
  this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer();
}
```

Comment: can you console 'this.refs' in handleMenuPress, see if it has drawer in it

Comment: error 'cannot read property 'openDrawer' of undefined , how to fix this sir ?

Comment: Please check whether you gave ref properly to DrawerLayoutAndroid. You can try this syntax  ref={(drawer) => { this.drawer = drawer; }} 
And instead of this.refs['DRAWER'].openDrawer(); use
this.drawer.openDrawer();

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the method inside the constructor (it is the best way).

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleMenuPress = this.handleMenuPress.bind(this)
}
```